# Bulk copying all inbox messages from MS Outlook Web Access to an offline folder

Tags: microsoft-outlook, web, outlook-web-access

How can I move a Microsoft Outlook Web Access inbox to an offline inbox? Can I download it using Microsoft Office 2011 for Mac?

Answer (score 9):

Select the emails required, Open a new email window, drag and drop the selected emails into the new email window and send it to the required email destination. All the selected emails get sent as attachments.

Comment: +1 this was a good answer, my org doesn't allow the export so this is how I was able to copy all my mail, thanks for the answer!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is there any way to allow dragging to the desktop?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Export feature to both Import and Export these files from outlook. The option is found in the Options windows under Advanced.

To Export: Export -> Export to File -> Outlook Data File (.pst)

To Import: Export -> Import from another program or file -> Outlook Data File (.pst)

Comment: this is not about Outlook but Outlook web access.

Answer (score -1):

2019 update - There now seems to be 2 versions of OWA (outlook.live.com, and outlook.office365.com).  These are slightly different but both are now almost functionality-free email and no save message function is provided - best solution is not to use it.
If you have to use it my solution is to set up a parallel gmail account and forward everything to that. Gmail still has a download message option from the Web Interface.