# Can you export your emails in Outlook Web App

Tags: outlook-web-access

I'm in need of backuping my emails in Outlook Web App but I can't find an export/import function in OWA. My question is:

Can you export emails from OWA and how?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

No you cannot. Outlook Web App is purely meant to send and receive email, but does not have a backup function.

If you want to backup email to an external medium, you will need a client such as Microsoft Outlook that supports this.

So, in order to make a proper backup, configure your account in a mailclient that supports making a backup. Just because OWA does not support it, doesn't mean its not possible. In modern mail clients such as MS Outlook and Thunderbird, just entering your email address and password automatically configures the client using autodiscovery. Not going for a mail client to make a backup and strictly limiting ones self to OWA is not necessary.

Comment: don't want to put as answer, because can not test, but you can try: http://smallbusiness.chron.com/archive-emails-outlook-access-52752.html

Comment: @Drako archiving an email is not the same as exporting. Archiving means, a flag is set and the email is marked as archived. It is moved from the inbox to the archive but remains on the server and has to be accessed differently. This makes it possible to keep the inbox speedy. AKA: not what OP wants.

Comment: I told I could not test, but archive can be local, if it's not in this case - then it's not.

Comment: I would have hoped for this https://superuser.com/a/1305796/30809 to have been the accepted answer. a workaround, but working nonetheless.

Answer (score 98):

[Here](https://outlook.uservoice.com/forums/313228--outlook-on-the-web-office-365/suggestions/13811895-saving-emails) is the enhancement request. You can drag and drop emails to add them as attachments as a workaround (see [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/847481/736703)). You can download an email like this:

1. Start a new message
2. Click to edit the message in a new window.
3. Select all emails you would like to download.
4. Drag the emails to the new message. This will add them as attachments.
5. Click the down arrow on the attachment and download the email message, or send the message to yourself and then download all attachments.

Comment: +1 This workaround has saved me! Currently I do have a limitation of only being able to save 40 at a time, but it'll take that over not being able to at all...

Comment: How are you supposed to read the downladed file again? I'ts a text format but attachments are in binary

Comment: This worked best, also included attachment! Only downside is it requires outlook or e-mail program to open attachment as @tiagosilva noticed

Comment: +1 I hate using the client version and was often forced to use it whenever I wanted to include an external email to a new email. This frees me from it :)

Comment: I am using Ubuntu and have no issue opening the email after using this workaround. The `.eml` file opens in GEdit perfectly fine (with all the email headers and body).

Comment: My file downloaded as "eml" with no file extension.  I changed it to "AnyName.eml" and it opened automatically in MS Outlook (the regular app, not the web app).

Comment: For me, I can add at most 30 MB of emails. If the draft keeps opening in edit view with all the attachments laid out, you can pop out the draft to see the compressed version with the download option back in the web app. Also when I download multiple, it just names it as "file" with no extension. After renaming it to something with ".zip", I can unzip all the emails.

Answer (score 7):

### Bulk export (save all emails)

Based on [Hans workaround](https://superuser.com/a/1305796/445903):

1. open a folder with the emails you want to export
2. scroll down to the earlier emails in that folder to load them all
3. use the check near the folder name to select them all

   [image: check all emails]
4. create a **New Message**
5. drag all emails to its body to make them as attachments

   [image: drag emails and drop as attachments]
6. scroll down and make sure that emails at the end are loaded (all should have their size displayed)

   [image: attachment size]
7. go to the **Drafts folder** and open the saved email
8. click on the **Download all** link:

   [image: download all attachments in a zip]

Comment: Thanks worked like a charm, though I had to email it back to myself to see the Download all. later on I noticed connecting to the local outlook on my windows 10 would make it all easier,

Comment: Looks like there's a limit to this workaround, as for 600+ attachments, clicking download all gives this: `{"Body":{"ErrorCode":500,"ExceptionName":"ErrorInvalidIdTooManyAttachmentLevelsException","FaultMessage":"Too many attachment levels.","IsTransient":false,"ResponseCode":"ErrorInternalServerError"}}`

Comment: This doesn't work if there are too many emails

Comment: As of 2023, you may need to email the draft to yourself before having the ability to download all.

Comment: As of 2023 there is no "Download all" option, or none I have found.

Comment: Correction:  I had *one* email out of 440 or so that for some reason OWA refuses to let me download, although it is happy to preview it and there's nothing special about it so far as I can tell.  That one attachment repeatedly suppressed "Download all" for increasingly smaller batches of emails, until I just downloaded each email in the final batch separately.  I never did get a copy of that one troublesome message.

Answer (score 3):

There is a commercial solution available from DragDrop that allows you to Drag emails and attachments and drop them anywhere (desktop, disk or any upload control)
https://www.dragdrop.com/dragdrop-online/

This way, no workaround is needed anymore.

Comment: Note: this is a *paid* app (€19 for single license), but offers a 7-day free trial.

Answer (score 0):

When viewing an email you want to download; 
Select the down arrow which is located on the top-right-hand corner of the email. Select "Print" and confirm "print" again. When your browser's print page window opens up, click "change destination" and select "save to PDF" from the list of printers. Click "Save".
Now you have a PDF version of that email.

Comment: Hi, this is not exactly what I'm looking for. What if you have thousands of emails you need to backup?

Comment: This doesn't save attachments

Comment: This doesn't save emails; it saves images of emails.  PDF is not a recognized mailbox format, and e.g. mutt won't be able to open it and treat it like an email, you can't feed one to maildrop or procmail and have it filtered into the proper mailbox, 'mu index' won't recognize it, etc.

Answer (score 0):

As there is no Import / Export option in Outlook Web Access to export emails, the only best way is to use a third-party application to save Outlook Web Access emails.

I would recommend you to try SysTools Office 365 Export Tool (for Office 365 Account) or SysTools Outlook.com Backup Tool (for Outlook.com account). Both these tools will get your job done with ease.